# Remove Question mark in url yii2?

Tags: yii2

how to remove ? in url yii2?

in rule :

```
'rules' => [
        '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
    ],
```

in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: remove  ?  in  ====>  web/page2?id=12

Comment: Why you did not add it in question? You can create rule (just like with this `alias` in your example) that will take `id`.

Comment: Bizley thanks. please rule for remove ? in url..

Comment: '<alias:\w+?>' => 'site/<alias>',  =====> correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this set of rules:

```
'<alias:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'site/<alias>',
'<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
```

Comment: for all get url must rule?

Comment: If you want make them part of URL separated with slashes - yes.

Comment: thanks. for example  : web/index.php?r=site%2Fproduct&id=2&id_post=3 
rule ?

Comment: Yes, here as well.

Comment: '<alias:\w+>/<id:\d+><id_post:\d+>' => 'site/<alias>',   ===>  is correct?